# Need to display tag group as first name, last name but sort on last name

Tags: tags

The reviewers for our site are listed as filtered tags by first name then last name.  How would I keep the display list as is but sort by last name?

I have now:

Aaron Smith
Bob Jones
Carl Harrison
Henry Adams
Steven Dunn

I would like it to list by last name:

Henry Adams
Steven Dunn
Carl Harrison
Bob Jones
Aaron Smith

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: Stan are you only referring to tags used on posts are these tags used in a tag cloud or any where else? do you using any other tags apart from the reviewers?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution. Assuming either the slugs for these tags are authors last name first or can be changed to be so. You can change the `orderby` on the `get_tags` to be done by the `slug` instead of the default `name`.

`$tags = get_tags( 'orderby=slug' );`

If you can provide a more complete overview of where you are using these tags I can probably provide a better example.